# Removing unwanted object keys & undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array:

```
const
    array1 = [
  {
    "value": "0",
    "name": "5",
    "waste": "remove",
    "city": "NY"
  },
  {
    "value": "0",
    "name": "51",
    "waste": "remove",
  }
]
```

So now, i wanted to remove certain and form a new array with objects: For example, i need to remove "Waste & value" and keep rest of the things, so i used this code:

```
var keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city']

const result = array2.map(e => {
  const obj = {};
  keys_to_keep.forEach(k => obj[k] = e[k])
  return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

And it gives a output as

```
[ { name: '5', city: 'NY' }, { name: '51', city: undefined } ]
```

Now as you can see city with undefined value, how to remove that ? i mean filter this and just show keys with value,

So my question is how to filter undefined and also is there any other better solution for removing unwanted object keys and showing new array with wanted keys ? or the method am using is performant enough ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value is undefined in your forEach:

```js
const result = array2.map(e => {
  const obj = {};
  keys_to_keep.forEach(k => { 
      if (undefined !== e[k]) {
          obj[k] = e[k]
      }
  )

  return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `e[k]` is defined before you add it to `obj` by checking whether the `e` object has the property `k` using [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```js
const array = [{ "value": "0", "name": "5", "waste": "remove", "city": "NY" }, { "value": "0", "name": "51", "waste": "remove", } ];

const keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city'];
const result = array.map(e => {
  const obj = {};
  keys_to_keep.forEach(k => {
    if (e.hasOwnProperty(k))
      obj[k] = e[k]
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

If the keys you want to remove aren't dynamic, you can also use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the properties you want to discard, and use the rest syntax to obtain an object without those properties:

```js
const array = [{ "value": "0", "name": "5", "waste": "remove", "city": "NY" }, { "value": "0", "name": "51", "waste": "remove", } ];
const result = array.map(({value, waste, ...r}) => r);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Amazing, both are working ! But which is performant efficient ? As my array usually contains around 40 keys ?

Comment: @Christina122 I would say the first snippet is more performant, as in that you only need to iterate the keys you want to keep

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer both the parts. So here are the steps to do that.

- Use `map()` on the main array.
- Get entries of each object using `Object.entries()`.
- Apply `filter()` on entires array are remove those entires for which key is not present in `keys_to_keep`

Now for the second part.

- Using `keys_to_keep` create an object which contain undefined values for each key.
- Use `map()` again on prev result and use Spread operator. First spread the object created above and then spread the original values. This way if any key is not found it will be set to `undefined`

```js
const
    array1 = [
  {
    "value": "0",
    "name": "5",
    "waste": "remove",
    "city": "NY"
  },
  {
    "value": "0",
    "name": "51",
    "waste": "remove",
  }
]
var keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city']
let obj = Object.fromEntries(keys_to_keep.map(x => [x, undefined]));
const res = array1.map(obj =>
                 Object.fromEntries(
                    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => keys_to_keep.includes(k))))
                    .map(x => ({...obj, ...x}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: It removes the entire city, my requirements is to remove if it contains undefined

Comment: @Christina122 My previous answer was fine I guess. But you didn't understood that I guess and make change all....

Comment: Comparing my approach and yours which would be effecient ?

Comment: @Christina122 What you mean by efficient?

Comment: @Christina122 In my code a totally new array of object is being generated and in you case you are mutating the object. If you are allowed to mutate it then yours is better. If you want I can add solution with mutation

Comment: My main array contains around 40 keys, thus comparing both approach would be performant efficient *

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the objects, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key-value pairs of each item, [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to group them into the resulting objects, and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get only the entries with a `key` in `keys_to_keep` and a `value` that is not `undefined`:

```js
const array1 = [
  { "value": "0", "name": "5", "waste": "remove", "city": "NY" },
  { "value": "0", "name": "51", "waste": "remove" }
];

var keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city'];

const result = array1.map(item =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).filter(([key, value]) =>
      keys_to_keep.includes(key) && value !== undefined
    )
  )
);
  
console.log(result)
```